# excluding vendor js files from jslint goal but not the compress goal in yuicompressor-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, yui-compressor

I have some third party js files in my project that I would like to minify during deployment, but I don't want to see the jslint warnings on those particular js files. How would I achieve this?

When I list both goals and exclude the js in the configuration, even the compress goal excludes them, as expected.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>compress</goal>
         <goal>jslint</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
     <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
     <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/min</webappDirectory>
     <excludes>
       <exclude>**/*min.js</exclude>
       <exclude>**/*min.css</exclude>
       <exclude>**/ZeroClipboard.js</exclude>
       <exclude>**/TableTools.js</exclude>
       <exclude>**/jquery.dataTables.rowGrouping.js</exclude>
     </excludes>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

But even when I put the configuration in the individual executions, jslint still shows me errors from the excluded js files.

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>minify</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>compress</goal>                    
          </goals>                  
          <configuration>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
              <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>                      
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>jslint</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jslint</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <excludes>
          <exclude>**/ZeroClipboard.js</exclude>
          <exclude>**/TableTools.js</exclude>
          <exclude>**/jquery.dataTables.rowGrouping.js</exclude>
          <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
          <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
        </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The above plugin configuration still shows jslint errors from the 3 listed js files. How do I avoid that?
Since they are 3rd party, I am not interested in fixing their jslint errors/warnings, but I'd still like them minified for my deployment purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Found it here : http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/usage_jslint.html

I could make it work having <configuration> under <plugin> not inside an <execution>